# Button disappearing when segue attached xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, button, segue

My system automatically upgrade from xcode 5 to 6 this morning. Now when I try to attach segue to a button, it shows correctly in the storyboard, but when I run the project in the simulator the button has disappeared and that area of the screen doesn't respond to a click.

Here's what I did:

1. I created a tab bar application
2. In tab 1, I added a button labeled "Tag" and some other elements.
3. I run the app, everything appears.
4. I added a table view to the storyboard.
5. I embeded the table view in a navigation controller.
6. I control-dragged from the Tag button to the navigation controller and the segue shows as created.
7. I run the app and there is no button on the tab bar view, but the other controls show.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a weird edge case. I had added the Tag button in XCode5 last night, but didn't wire it up till this morning and it disappeared. All of my other actions had been connected yesterday and they worked.

I added a new button in XCode6 and it wires up fine and the segue works. So I guess the Tag button somehow got screwed up via the upgrade.